# How to ask an outdated question if I cannot comment?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, comments, outdated-information

I recently asked a question that has already been asked on SO but is outdated:

[Close Browser without Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807111/close-browser-without-prompt)

I got down voted because it is a duplicated question. Understandable. A user informed me to comment on that question asking asking for an update as the discussed methods no longer work. I cannot comment because my reputation is not high enough. Does that mean I'm left in the dark on this one? What's a solution to this problem (getting an update - not my coding issue at hand)?

Comment: Give a couple quality answers and get to 50 rep?

Comment: I placed a bounty on the old question.

Comment: Isn't asking jlrosenberg to comment on the original question asking for an update frowned upon on SO?  I didn't think comments should be used for such purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey woah, nice guy moderator :P

Comment: I'd also point out to the guy who said "comment the old question" that there's already a comment from June 2013, the answerer (is that even a word?) doesn't seem to what to provide an update.

Comment: @codeMagic Make another account and give it a try. You will see if that is so easy nowadays to get upvotes and accepted answers when you are flagged as a newcomer. I especially dislike your comment, because most askers are beginners and you need to learn and get some experience before you can begin to transmit it to others

Comment: @Aldian I do have a test account and I would do this experiment to show you except I'm trying to keep that rep low for now. Anyway, no one is "flagged" as a newcomer. They are treated the same as someone who has been here awhile. I am just as likely (if not more so) to upvote and answer/question by someone new as I am with a high rep user. Yes, you do need to learn before teaching others but I have learned a lot by answering questions I knew nothing about.

Answer (score 64):

If the answer to the previous question does not work for yours because the previous asker was using a different version of a software, then your questions are **not** duplicates.

Even though the previous question didn't specify the version, the OP was using an older browser at the time(it was 2008), and your question is specific to IE 10 or higher.

If you make it clear that you're using a different version than the other question, and that the answer to the other question didn't work, then it is wrong for people to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: That was my thought process...

Comment: Everyone who agrees with this should go vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Just agreed with you Sam I am. Voted to reopen as @Marcin Said. One more hand required to open that question. *Edit :* It's opened now. Kudos to all.

Comment: I was going to vote but it's already opened :-)

Comment: When I ask a question similar to another one, I explicitly link it in my question, explaining that it gives me some starting hints, and why I need a better answer. That way I avoid being flagged to fast as a duplicate and my question shows that I made some research effort

Answer (score 12):

Technically it's not a duplicate, but you should make it more clear. Since you are targeting the specific browser and version, you should point it out:

- by using proper tags: [internet-explorer-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-10)
- by using proper title: Close Browser without Prompt **(IE 10 and above)**

Optionally, you can also edit the "original" question to point out the targeted browser versions, so that question is no more obsolete, only limited to obsolete browsers.